# Custom authentication in wcf without certificate, https, ssl and iis

Tags: wcf, security, iis, authentication, https

First of all sorry for my English, its not my native language. I will try to describe my problem as much as I can.

I searched for a long time on the Internet for a solution where I can create a wcf service that can respond to requests of my clients with username and password required but without creating a certificate, using https or anything else that require a special configuration on the machine where my windows service will be installed.

Here is my point: I want to deploy an application to a lot of my customers. This application will have mobile devices and a server which will give some information to mobile device with the help of wcf. Each customer will have a server and many devices. I don't want that anyone on the web can have access to these information and for this reason, I must implement an authentication procedure with username and password for each request but I don't want to be forced to install a certificate, activate some https port on each machine when I sell a new copy of my application.

I've read that with wcf 4.0, there is a built-in system that can encrypt data and for this reason, I don't want the overhead of implementing anything else if possible.

My question is: Is that possible to have a secure solution considering my requirements and if yes, how can I do that?

If I really must create a certificate and use IIS, https or any other secure solution, it is possible to automate these things in a package that will be installed in a single click wizard into each server machine of my customers?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

By default WCF doesnt allow transport of username credentials over http and hence have to use certificates to secure your transport layer. But if you are sure that you are fine with sending username credentials over the http channel then you can have a look at [ClearUsernameBinding](http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2008/11/introducing-wcf-clearusernamebinding.html) which gives you the flexibility of sending username credentials over http channel (consider the fact that someone can intercept your transport channel to get access to the credentials)

Also if you want to use certificates that have to be installed you can achieve that writing some code in c# and include that as part of your installation from your package. You can also configure everything from an msi like creating a virtual directory, deploying the application,etc..

Comment: You can change the transport to not require security since .net 3.5 this will send the username and password in the header in http.

Answer (score 0):

what you are probably looking for is one of the wcf bindings that has message level security.  You can put the user name and password into this message and not worry about them going across an http wire unencrypted(ie custom authentication).  The defaults for WCF send user name and password as part of the http request in the header this is why it wants https.